# Looping in Powershell I

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to run a powershell script where I can loop a command until it comes back false.

```
tnc -ComputerName [Address] -port [port]
Start-Sleep -s 5
```

The script is run every 5 seconds

```
ComputerName     : [Address]
RemoteAddress    : IP
RemotePort       : Port
InterfaceAlias   : WiFi
SourceAddress    : [Address]
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

I need this to run every 5 seconds but only show on false then extract to a doc and continue running.

I don't know if this is possible, but any help

Comment: You already have the logic to do the `Test-NetConnection`, just need to apply a `while` or `do` loop to it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while?view=powershell-7.2 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Hi Santiago, I'm very sorry.

I'm not very good (yet) at this. 

I have attempted do complete what has been shown but I'm missing something?
Do {tnc address-port port -InformationLevel Quiet} until (<False>)

Comment: Also is there away to time stamp the results?

Comment: If you’re not picky about the date format you can just use ``Get-Date``. Otherwise you can use ``Get-Date -Format``. You can look up Get-Date to see format styles

Comment: got the date/time,  thank you :) just can't work out the false now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic would look like this, note that, there are many variations for this. It's up to you.

- `DateTime.ToString('u')` will have the following format for `TimeStamp`:

```
//    u Format Specifier      de-DE Culture                     2008-10-31 17:04:32Z
//    u Format Specifier      en-US Culture                     2008-10-31 17:04:32Z
//    u Format Specifier      es-ES Culture                     2008-10-31 17:04:32Z
//    u Format Specifier      fr-FR Culture                     2008-10-31 17:04:32Z
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0

```
$log = do # Do this
{
    # Store the result of TNC in this variable to be tested until(...) is False
    $tnc = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName [Address] -Port [port] |
    Select-Object @{
        Name = 'TimeStamp'
        Expression = { [datetime]::Now.ToString('u') }
    }, RemoteAddress, RemotePort, TcpTestSuceeded

    # Return this variable so it's captured in $log Variable to export the log later
    $tnc 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
until ($tnc.TcpTestSuceeded) # Until this property is $False

$log | Export-Csv path/to/logfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I shall give this a bash, thank you

Comment: @Gary no problem, if the answer was helpful please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it.

Comment: Thank you, working as I needed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  But the timeout of a down connection is ridiculously long at about 30 seconds.

```
while ( -not (tnc yahoo.com -port 81) ) { sleep 5 }

WARNING: TCP connect to (2001:4998:24:120d::1:1 : 81) failed
WARNING: TCP connect to (2001:4998:124:1507::f001 : 81) failed
```